# VPN slowlyness fixed with MTU, but connection problems to extern networks

Tags: vpn, mtu

I was facing some issues with the VPN Performance of Windows 2012 and Windows 2016 VPN. I was not able to get high data exchange rates. It took minutes to open a 3 MB excel file.

I then reduced the MTU to 1372 which is the biggest package I can send without DF.

BUT if I reduce the MTU, i can't access some external website any more. Google is possible but not www.wieistmeineip.de (for example). With MTU set to 1500 I can access every page but with a really slow VPN. Any ideas?

I've used this KB to change the MTU: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/826159/how-to-change-the-default-maximum-transmission-unit-mtu-size-settings

Maybe it is an ISP issue.
I've tested it with my ISP (using IPv4) the MTU working for me is 1372. Lower MTUs will not work to access each website / establish a connection to every server.
Another test with another ISP (using IPv6) works with lower MTU 1300 to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that a VPN encapsulates packets, thus decreasing the maimum packet size that can be sent.

The ways to handle this is to either do my clamping in the router - IF it supports it, or to modify the VPN to fragment packets (mssfix and fragment options).

Also make sure you don't block all icmp as this blocks mtu discovery.

As an aside - was 1372 a typo? That would be very low - 1472 would seem a lot more likely.

Comment: Nope not a typo. The maximum Packet size I can use to ping is 1372. I've added the 28 for the ip header and configured 1400 now in the registry. It seemes to be working now. The copying of files is fast and i can access these websites at once. I will test it today and let you know. I don't know why I can't work with 1472.

Comment: Okay, with 1372 user from another ISP than mine can not use the VPN. I have to set a lower to get it working for them. But a lower MTU results in errors on my side.

Comment: Maybe it's an ipv4 and ipv6 issue. My ISP is using ipv4. And needs the higher MTU to work. Another ISP is using ipv6 and needs the lower MTU. How can i solve this?